# Query and Eager-Load Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have 2 models with the following fields to be queried.

- `Customer`

  - `:first_name`
  - `:last_name`
  - `:address`
  - `:email`
- `Relatives`

  - `:first_name`
  - `:last_name`
  - `:address`
  - `:title`

A `Customer` has many `Relatives`.

I am trying to write a `search()` method that will return a collection of `Customer` records where *either* the fields of the `Customer` or 1+ of it's related `Relatives` match the query.

The goal is to be able to iterate a collection of `Customer` records. If `customer.relatives.present?`, I will know to loop through the related `Relative` models provided with the `Customer` - that the models in that collection match the query.

I currently have something like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relatives

  def self.search(params={})
    cols  = %i(address caseworker last_name)
    conds = []

    cols.reject! { |col| params[col].blank? }

    conds << cols.collect { |col| "clients.#{col} like ?" }.join(" or ")
    cols.each { |col| conds << "%#{params[col]}%" }

    query = self.send(:where, conds)

    # @todo query relatives here!    
  end

end
```

Where I get stuck:

- I can't figure out the ARel to join/merge/union/(I dont know the term I'm looking for) the `Customer` models that don't match the search, but **do** have a `Relative` matching the search.

  - I believe I need a nearly identical `search()` on the `Relative` model - which I believe I can write - but am again unsure how fill out the `@todo` above to eager-load only those `Relative` that match the query.

I'm looking for any bump in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your database, you might want to look into something like [`pg_search`](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) for full-text searching.

After the search indexes are built, eager-loading Relatives that match the Customer query is trivial.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  has_many :relatives

  pg_search_scope :search,
    :against => [:address, :caseworker, :last_name]
    :associated_against => {
    :relatives => [:address, :caseworker, :last_name]
  }
end

Customer.search("foobar").preload(:relatives)
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Do you know of a MySQL equivalent?

Comment: Also, the `preload(:relativates)` will load **all** relatives, when I'm only interested in those that specifically caused the `Customer` to be included in the original set.

Comment: I don't have any experience with full text search in MySQL, but Thinking Sphinx (http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) looks promising

Comment: And sorry, I missed the requirement about only eager-loading the Relatives that matched the query. I'll have a think about that..

Answer (score 0):

This gem is a simple implementation of search and full-text search for mysql databases https://github.com/makandra/dusen

You might have to do a bit of coding to make the gem working properly such as define search_text etc. But this gem would take care of the rest.